# Definition of Java's mark-preclean-sweep-reset GC lines?

Tags: java, content-management-system, jvm, verbosegc

Can someone please provide some insight into the the following verbosegc lines on  a Java runtime with CMS GC enabled?  Specifically:

1. Does the event at `29.490` indicate heap location of the highwater for marking?
2. What is the `preclean` phase and what is it doing different than marking?
3. What is the `reset` phase?  Why would that take time to complete if it is not just the end of the sweep?
4. Finally, what is the `Rescan`, `grey` and `root` rescans and `remark` areas and metrics on the event at `29.653`?  Shall we assume these are just reported heap metrics for the subsequent sweep?  If so why do they consume time?

verbosegc log excerpt:

```
29.490: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 16225K(17684K)] 16737K(22420K), 0.0030839 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
29.494: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
29.652: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.158/0.158 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs]
29.652: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
29.652: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
29.653: [GC[YG occupancy: 512 K (4736 K)]29.653: [Rescan (non-parallel) 29.654: [grey object rescan, 0.0001517 secs]29.654: [root rescan, 0.0030887 secs], 0.0033817 secs]29.657: [weak refs processing, 0.0000271 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 16225K(17684K)] 16737K(22420K), 0.0035183 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
29.658: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
29.679: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.022/0.022 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
29.680: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
29.703: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.022/0.022 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
29.797: [GC 29.797: [DefNew: 4736K->512K(4736K), 0.0207183 secs] 20800K->17172K(31512K), 0.0209119 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the ["Understanding Concurrent Mark Sweep Garbage Collector Logs"](http://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/understanding_cms_gc_logs) article on the Sun website.  I think that answers most of your questions about the logs.  For more background information on Java's Concurrent GC, refer to the ["Java SE 6 HotSpot[tm] Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning"](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html) page.